# How can I create a virtual screen?

Tags: 22.04

I want to set up a dual screen without connecting an extra screen. I want to use the virutal screen to be casted to another screen (which is not connected to the laptop). However I'm not able to do it, I tried this:

```
xrandr --addmode VIRTUAL1 1024x768
xrandr: cannot find output "VIRTUAL1"
```

What can I try?
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS